# What's the alternative to public methods when you switch from class-based to function-based React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

React components that use hooks can't be class-based; they have to be function-based.  There's something I used to do in class-based components that I'm not sure how to accomplish in function-based components: calling a method on a child component.

The context where this comes up for me is in components that act like a map, or like a photoshop document.  They often have a way of zooming to a specific area, while also allowing the user to freely pan around afterward.

One might design such a `<Zoomable>` component to keep internal state about where it's zoomed to, but provide a public method `zoomTo(place)`.

One could use the Zoomable component like this:

```
const ZoomableUI = ({place}) => {
    const zoomable = React.useRef(null)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        zoomable.zoomTo(place)
    }, [place])

    return (
        <div>
            <Zoomable ref={zoomable} />
            <button onClick={() => zoomable.current.zoomTo(place)}>
                Re-Center
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This component causes the Zoomable to zoom to a place when it first renders, or when the `place` property changes, but the user could freely pan around theirself afterward.  They could then re-center it on the current place by clicking the button.

Of course, none of this would work if the Zoomable was implemented as a function-based component.  How would you implement this sort of system with a function-based map?

What's the alternative to providing public methods when you switch to function-based React components?

Btw, don't suggest that I just put the button inside the Zoomable.  Its purpose is to serve as an example of behavior that could come from anywhere in the app, not necessarily somewhere co-located in the DOM.

Comment: Out of question but, how do you make that answer for yourself only 10 seconds after the question?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have public private methods, in fact JavaScript doesn't have methods at all, It's not a OOP language

Answer (score 0):

You could turn Zoomable into a fully controlled component.  Then the parent component would need to manage its zoom level and position.

```
const ZoomableUI = ({place}) => {
    const [mapState, setMapState] = React.useState(place)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setMapState(place)
    }, [place])

    return (
        <div>
            <Zoomable state={mapState} setState={setMapState} />
            <button onClick={() => setMapState(place)}>
                Re-Center
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Another possibility I see is to pass the place in as a prop.  Zoomable could have an internal `useEffect` that would zoom it to the place when the place changed.  This wouldn't work for the button though, since the button doesn't change the prop.  I could put a counter in the Zoomable's `key` prop to cause it to refresh its state.

```
const ZoomableUI = ({place}) => {
    const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0)
    return (
        <div>
            <Zoomable place={place} key={counter} />
            <button onClick={() => setCounter((counter) => counter + 1)}>
                Re-Center
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```